# Delete row from table

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to delete the current row displayed in jframe from the table contact

I wrote the code

```
try
    {
        conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "usrnme", "pswd");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);//also tried with ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE
        rs.deleteRow();
        rs.next();//it may or may not include in code
    }
    catch(Exception e){System.out.println( "JDBC error: " + e );}
```

sql query

```
 String sql="SELECT * FROM contact order by first_name, last_name";
        rs=stmnt.executeQuery(sql);
```

but it throws an exception while running

```
 JDBC error: java.sql.SQLException: 'deleteRow' not allowed because the ResultSet is not an updatable ResultSet.
```

Help me!

Comment: Not all DBMS and JDBC drivers allow this. Which DBMS are you using? You should also show us the SQL statement that you used to create the ResultSet. Is there any reason you don't just use a `delete from ... where ...`?

Comment: i used java DB as my database and the codes i written for adding new row, move next and move previous are working fine.

Comment: Modify your sql statement. Without using * in the statement just give the all column name.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : How can I use delete from statement? my table has no primary key. it only contains first_name, last_name, address and phoneno fields

Comment: @ricky2527 : No change, the same exception

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it totally in SQL, where you need to additionally select the (internal) `rowid` of every row

```
SELECT c.*, c.rowid FROM contact c ORDER BY first_name, last_name
```

and afterward delete a row by it row id

```
DELETE FROM contact c WHERE c.rowid  = (?)
```

this works for Oracle, but every Databasetype does use internal `rowid`'s. For MYSQl you get the rowid by using `@rowid` as far as I remember

Comment: I would just try it. The Oracle documentaion says that it's not supported. But it also states that MySQL does not support rowid's (which is not true) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlrowid.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, try ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE. That might do the trick. If that doesn't work, try an [SQL DELETE statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp) (w3schools.com) instead to delete the row.

Edit: Now that I reread your code: you need to move to the next row *before* you call `deleteRow`. Opening a statement sets the cursor *before* the first row. If your call to `next` returns true, your cursor points to the first row. Only if the cursor points to a valid row can you delete the row. HTH.

Comment: I already tried ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE. No difference.

Comment: I don't think so. And even if try to delete a row other than first row it throws same exception. Any way I tried it and it is not helping.

Comment: @Justin I fear I'm at the limit of what I can do to help. The only thing I can advise you with is to upgrade your JDBC driver. Maybe it has a bug, or it does not support deletion. If that doesn't help you are probably restricted to running a SQL `DELETE` statement. In general, you are best to come with a SET based solution to your problem and void `CURSOR`s. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To make use of `updatable ResultSet` , your table must contain `primary key` column. It is the link between data present in ResultSet and DB. Since I infer from your comments your table does not contain primary key, you can delete row using sql query.

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM contact WHERE first_name='test'";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

Comment: I made some changes in the table and added a new column id as primary key. but still deleteRow() doesn't work.

Comment: Now change your statement to createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);` and try. Also make sure the SQL query you run includes the primary key in resultset, like `select id,first_name from...`. Also make sure to set the cursor on appropriate row `rs.absolute(5);rs.deleteRow();`